# SSH multiple HOP

Tags: ssh, tunneling

I have 3 workstations

- ortro (my client)
- idrauser@idra (the middle)
- cerberouser@cerbero (the destination)

On idra:

```
ssh -L 9999:idra:22 cerberouser@cerbero
```

On otro:

```
ssh idrauser@idra -p 9999
ssh: connect to host idra port 9999: Connection refused
```

I cannot modify the sshd_config in ortro. I need to setup a tunnel between idra and cerbero and then use it from ortro

Thanks a lot
Riccardo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ssh tunnel to a computer and create another tunnel a third server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746246/ssh-tunnel-to-a-computer-and-create-another-tunnel-a-third-server)

Answer (score 4):

`-L` binds to localhost by default.

Use

```
ssh -L '*':9999:idra:22 cerberouser@cerbero
```

or

```
ssh -o GatewayPorts=yes -L 9999:idra:22 cerberouser@cerbero
```

instead.

---

A more secure solution would not proxy the port, but instead proxy the connection. Try adding this to your `~/.ssh/config` on ortro:

```
Host cerbero
User cerberouser
ProxyCommand /usr/bin/ssh idrauser@idra /bin/nc -w 3700 %h %p
```

Then connect to cerbero from ortro by running the single command

```
ssh cerbero
```

Answer (score 0):

These days SSH has specific shortcuts for host jumping. See [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73255131/241211).

```bash
ssh -J idrauser@idra cerberouser@cerbero
```

Or in SSH Config (just your local `~/.ssh/config` one, not SSHD Config)

```bash
Host cerbero
    User cerberouser
    ProxyJump idra

Host idra
    User idrauser
```

and `ssh cerbero`.