# SSH port forwarding through 2 jump servers

Tags: portforwarding, ssh-tunnel, jumphost

I am trying to connect to a server behind a firewall.

For this connection I have to use more than one jump server.
So I SSH `local` → `user1@jump1` → `user2@jump2` → `user3@server`.
I can connect directly to the server with

```bash
ssh -J user1@jump1,user2@jump2 user3@server
```

I want to tunnel a connection between Sublime Text on my local computer and `rmate` on the destination server. I followed the instructions on [data36](https://data36.com/sublime-text-data-science-remote-server/). In the description, the user just connects to one server with

```
ssh -R 52698:localhost:52698 user3@server
```

I have not found something similar for **three** servers. Is there an option to do this? Maybe someone could give me an example with the ports.

I have tried

```
ssh  -R 52698:localhost:52698,52698:jump1:52698, 52698:jump2:52698, 52698:server:52698 -J user1@jump1,user2@jump2 user3@server
```

but this gives me the error:

> Bad remote forwarding specification 52698:localhost:52698,52698:jump1:52698,52698:jump2:52698,52698:server:52698

The names `jump1`, `jump2`, and `server` stand for the respective IP addresses. So in the real `ssh` command, I use IP addresses and not names.

Answer (score 2):

You were overthinking it. Port forwarding isn't done jump-to-jump on each connection. You establish the tunnel through all the links, and then forward your ports through the tunnel.

```bash
ssh -J user1@jump1,user2@jump2 -R 52698:localhost:52698 user3@server
```

On the command line with `-J`, the configuration *must include* the server and *can also include* user and/or port: `[user@]host[:port]`.

### Standardizing

To make things easy (or to include other parameters for the jump hosts), put the config in *~/.ssh/config*:

```
Host jump1
    Hostname 1.1.1.1
    User user1

Host jump2
    Hostname 2.2.2.2
    User user2
    ProxyJump jump1

Host server
    Hostname 3.3.3.3
    User user3
    ProxyJump jump2
    RemoteForward 52698
```

Then `ssh server` on the CLI will do all the hops and port forwarding automatically.

Comment: What if the ports are different, e.g. `local, p8080 → user1@jump1, p1111 → user2@jump2, p2222 → user3@server,p3333`? Also, if I can only set jump1 and jump2 in ssh config (e.g. server changes frequently, such as in job management systems like HTCondor or slurm), what would the ssh command be?

Comment: @TuBui Updated the answer. If the destination server always changes, you can still configure the jumps and `-J` the last hop: `ssh -J jump2 user3@slurm -p 3333`. If you can run a script to get the server(s)' connection info, you can [throw it into a file to be `Include`d by your main `ssh_config`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55732215/241211).

Answer (score 0):

The reason the command isn't working is that `jump1` and `jump2` don't have corresponding `rmate` servers listening on those particular ports and forwarding on the the next server, so the signal dies at `jump1`. If you have shell accounts on `jump1` and `jump2`, you could [set up](https://github.com/randy3k/RemoteSubl#installation) `rmate` on each one, as well as on the final `server` box.

Theoretically this should work, but I don't have any way of testing it. For more help, you can also try posting on the official [Sublime Text Forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com) to see if anyone with more experience than I can give you some suggestions.